Why does Steve’s behavior appear contradictory in this scene?
Amidst the tension of Steve Dallas’s confrontation with J.J. in the
TV studio, Susie, the object of Steve’s affection and J.J.'s sister,
subtly moved to a corner within the same studio:

J.J: Suppose you just shuffle along and call it a day.
Steve: But my day with Susie isn't over yet.
J.J : Here's your head. What's your hurry?

And then Steve leaves the studio
Steve states that his day with Susie isn’t over yet, implying that he intends to
spend more time with her. However, he then leaves the scene, which contradicts
his previous statement.
Why does Steve’s behavior appear contradictory in this scene?

Because JJ is telling him to leave in no uncertain terms, surely?
